# Lodash throttle - prevent function from being called an extra time after delay

Tags: javascript, lodash

I wanted to use lodash throttle to make a function callable not more than once every 4 seconds or so.

If the user tries to activate the function multiple times in succession, only the first click should start the function. However the function is called **an extra time** after the delay. It is called once immediately and once again after the delay.

How do I prevent the extra call?

```js
thing = _.throttle(function() {
  console.log('function runs');
}, 4000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>

<button onclick="thing()">click a few times</button>
```

([*fiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/galivan/c8pbuqr2/))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
thing =  _.throttle( function() {

   $('#info').append('function runs' + '<br />') 

}, 4000, {trailing:false});
```

https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle

Comment: What is the difference between this and `debounce` with the same options?

Comment: Can someone explain why this works or what it even does?

Comment: @xr280xr TLDR; from docs: "Note: If leading and trailing options are true, func is invoked on the trailing edge of the timeout only if the throttled function is invoked more than once during the wait timeout." A good explanation for me is "The Debounce technique allow us to “group” multiple sequential calls in a single one." and "The main difference between throttle and debouncing is that throttle guarantees the execution of the function regularly, at least every X milliseconds." https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/ helps